# Strange behavior/loading patterns when using React + Meteor pre-filling forms

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Cliffs:

I'm trying to pre-fill forms from a user's previous entries, which is all stored in a MongoDB colelction I do this doing conventional Javascript:

```
componentDidMount(){
 let name = document.getElementById("name");
    name.value = this.props.iData.name;
}
```

This works fine unless I refresh the page, in which case I get an error that `this.props.iData` is undefined. So, whenever I visit the page with the pre-filled data, it works fine and subscription works fine. But when I refresh that same page, the subscription doesn't load fast enough.

The subscription is done like this:

```
export default createContainer(function(){
  const subHandle = Meteor.subscribe("iData", function(){
  });
  const isLoading = !subHandle.ready();
  return {
    isLoading,
    iData: Poll.find().fetch(),
  }
}, UserSettings)
```

I must be doing something wrong for this to happen the way it's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure that your data is ready when componentDidMount is getting called. And also you shouldnt use document.getElementById() in react.

In react you need to use refs.

```js
class Sample extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref.input.value = 'some value';
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <input ref="input" />
    );
  }
}
```

You can also do this:

```js
class Sample extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {!this.props.isLoading ? (
             <input value = {this.props.someValue}/>
            ) : (
              <p>Loading </p>
            )}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to use refs instead of ids. Anyway, I make sure that the data is loaded before the `componentDidMount()` fires, but I'm still having the same errors when I refresh the page or click the back button.